# How to create a table-value parameter for text command

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

I have a generated block of SQL query that takes a table-value parameter as an input.

I have a `DataTable data` input parameter, then:

```
// add the table-value parameter
var tvp = com.Parameters.AddWithValue("data", data);
tvp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
tvp.TypeName = "???";

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is that if the command is not a stored procedure then the `TypeName` needs to be declared.

The number and type of columns in the `data` parameter could vary a lot, so I don't have a SQL type that I can use.

Is there any way that I can use a TVP in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have a defined TypeName on the server end in order to pass a table valued parameter.  So if non exists, then no... you cannot use a table valued parameter in this way.  Read more on limitations and requirements here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx

I haven't ever tried it but there shouldn't be any reason that you couldn't generate the create TypeName statement prior to this block of code based on structure of your datatable.  You could pick any name you want and then drop it when you're done.

It would take a little coding to build the create typename statement based on the structure of your datatable but do-able.

Comment: Yeah, that's the route that I went down, but after much messing around I found it to be scarily slow. At first I thought it was due to dynamically creating the type, but all TVP calls are slow. It looks like, under the hood, the the TVP is build with an `insert into` statement *per row!* It's much quicker (we're talking seconds to milliseconds) to build your own dynamically or even use `SqlBulkCopy`. I think .Net's TVP implementation might be broken, because if it used one `insert into` with `,` separated value collections it would so be much quicker.

Comment: Good info, thanks for posting your experience.  Your question intrigued me and I was going to try it out later when I had a chance to see if I could make it work.